# auth log seems to be running mystery cronjob

Tags: 16.04, bash, cron

I looked at my auth log to see if bots were attempting to gain access and I saw a cronjob that seems to be running but I cannot see why. This is what the auth log looks like...

```
Dec  7 13:55:01 myuser CRON[7362]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  7 13:55:01 myuser CRON[7362]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec  7 14:05:01 myuser CRON[7385]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  7 14:05:01 myuser CRON[7385]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec  7 14:15:01 myuser CRON[7408]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  7 14:15:01 myuser CRON[7408]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

so it is running every ten minutes on the dot. When I look at my root crontab I see this.

```
#0      0       *       *       *       job.sh
0       0       *       *       *       job2.sh
#0      23      *       *       *       job3.sh
0       0       */10    *       *       job4.sh
0       0       */5     *       *       job5.sh
```

Some jobs are commented out on purpose. I see only one things that has a */10 interval but that is in the day column not the minute column....Any idea where I can look next?

sudo -u root crontab -l:

```
#0  0   *   *   *   job.sh
0   0   *   *   *   job2.sh
#0  23  *   *   *   job3.sh
0   0   */10    *   *   job4.sh
0   0   */5 *   *   job5.sh
```

/etc/crontab:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

I did a `cat *` of the `cron.d` dir and edited out all comments and got this:

```
57 0 * * 0 root if [ -x /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray ] && [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ]; then /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --cron --all --idle --quiet; fi
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
31 21 * * *   root    test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond
PATH=/usr/lib/sysstat:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
59 23 * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 60 2
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -u root crontab -l`, `/etc/crontab`, and also check all files in `/etc/cron.d/`

Comment: added...there seems to be one in the cron.d dir but IDK what it is

Answer (score 2):

As seen, these are from:

```
5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
```

and the command `debian-sa1` (`/usr/lib/sysstat/debian-sa1`), is basically a wrapper script, is from the `sysstat` package. The filename in `/etc/cron.d/` should be `sysstat`.

More confirmation:

```
% dpkg -S /usr/lib/sysstat/debian-sa1
sysstat: /usr/lib/sysstat/debian-sa1

% dpkg -S /etc/cron.d/sysstat 
sysstat: /etc/cron.d/sysstat
```

and the comment above the line is:

```
# Activity reports every 10 minutes everyday
5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
```

`debian-sa1` is calling `/usr/lib/sysstat/sa1` which in turn is calling `sadc` eventually.